# Moongose find by ObjectId bringing empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to find all articles that match certain user id.

This is the schema:

```
const articleSchema = new DB.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  body: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: DB.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  likes: [String],
  shares: [String],
  comments: [
    {
      text: String,
      user: String,
    },
  ]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

This is the controller which is not working:

```
const handleGetAllByUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  try {
    let articles = await Article.find({ user: userId }).populate('user', 'name');
    return res.status(200).json({ articles });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  }
};
```

I also tried doing this:

```
Article.find({user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)};
```

I know this has been answered before, it's not something complex, I just can't picture what's going wrong.

Comment: Could you add the `User` schema as well?

Comment: Something like this should work `Article.find({ 'user.id': userId })`. Replace `id` if you have any other key.

Answer (score 1):

You get the user ID from the request parameter, e.g. it is the string representation of the ObjectId. Your model defines the user as a ObjectId, e.g. a binary.

You need to convert the string to ObjectId:

```
    let articles = await Article.find({ user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }).populate('user', 'name');`
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that certain articles had been saved with user as String: [image]

For some reason none of the queries suggested worked.
The fix was to update that data type to ObjecId, thus:
[image]

Then one can simply write:

```
Article.find({ user: userId }).populate('user', 'name');
```

This one works. There's no even need to convert to ObjectId manually, since mongoose seems to do this already on the background.